# How to add regular expression to match alphanumeric character with some special characters

Tags: java, regex

I have the words with special character like

```
Ex: ABC12-xy
    ABCD
    ABC12_12
    12-AB_xy
```

I have tried the following but not working

```
'(-\\w+)'   ,   '[-A-Za-z_0-9]'
```

But not working.

Comment: Have you tried any regex tools to experiment? Also the regex cheat sheet ( http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ ) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
[\w-]+
```

Which matches all below

```
ABC12-xy
ABCD
ABC12_12
12-AB_xy
```

Answer (score 1):

use `[\w-]+` to match the entire string. You can use `^` and `$` to specify the start and the end of the line. For example `^[\w-]+$` would match the entire line only if the line has all word or `-` characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+";
System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "ABC12-xy"));
System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "ABCD"));
System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "ABC12_12"));
System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "12-AB_xy"));
```